# mocking the populate method using mockgoose for mongoose (mongodb library for node.js) is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocking

Having trouble debugging an issue that mockgoose has for populating a property with fields set.  Yads mockgoose http://github.com/yads/Mockgoose fork solved the bug of making the populate option work, but if you specify fields it returns a null for the populated property.  I tried looking through the source code and stepping through with the debugger but not sure where to look.  I can see in the debugger that the populate option triggers a call to get the child element - and I see the call made returns the right child result with the correct fields, but when the parent element finally comes back it has the property to the child element set to null.

The query:

```
Posts.findById(foo).populate('createdBy', {fname:1, lname:1});
```

Incorrectly returns a post with post.createdBy = null.  Omitting the fields parameter of fame, lname, somehow makes it work again with post.createdBy returning the full object.

Following are some excerpts from the code - though I'm not sure those are the right places to look.

collections.js

```
this.find = function (conditions, options, callback) {
    var results;
    var models = db[name];
    if (!_.isEmpty(conditions)) {
        results = utils.findModelQuery(models, conditions);
    } else {
        results = utils.objectToArray(utils.cloneItems(models));
    }
    results = filter.applyOptions(options, results);

    if (results.name === 'MongoError') {
        callback(results);
    } else {
        var result = {
            toArray: function (callback) {
                callback(null, results);
            }
        };
        callback(null, result);
    }
};
```

util.js

```
function cloneItems(items) {
    var clones = {};
    for (var item in items) {
        clones[item] = cloneItem(items[item]);
    }
    return clones;
}

function cloneItem(item) {
    return _.cloneDeep(item, function(value) {
        // Do not clone items that are ObjectId objects as _.clone mangles them
        if (value instanceof ObjectId) {
            return new ObjectId(value.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

And here's a conversation about the issue

https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose/pull/90